# Density of points on graph

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a scatter graph with points placed on it like:

[image]

I am trying to find an equation that gives me the density of the points on the graph, for example the points on this graph:

[image]

are closer together so it would have a higher density than something like this:

[image]

I apologize if i am not using the proper terminology or anything, i'm not very good at math..

Edit:
To clarify, each point has a x/y coordinate and i do have the max x/y coordinate for the graph. The points are placed at their coordinate within the max x/y coordinates.

Comment: If they are absolutely randomly placed, the expected density won't give you much info.

Comment: You need to supply the area with respect to which the density is being calculated. Is it the smallest rectangle encompassing the points? The smallest circle? What?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question but the smallest circle covering the area of the points should work. I have the max x/y coordinates for the graph and the x/y coordinates for each point. The points are placed randomly within the max x/y coordinates.