# Method for computing density of points within a polygon

Tags: geometry

I was wondering if anybody knows a way to quantify the "density" of points contained within a polygon.

Here are my assumptions:

1. The polygon is convex.
2. All of the points' location is known.
3. Currently, I would like to limit the problem to two dimensions, but would like to know the implications of moving it to higher dimensions (n-polytope).

I realize this is similar to the following question: [Density of points on graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938129/density-of-points-on-graph) however I am only concerned about the density within the polygon.

Idea so far:

1. Compute all the distances between each object in the polygon.
2. Compute the standard deviation between the distances.
3. A higher deviation would signify a greater variation between the distances between points.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious and straight-forward definition of a point density would be number of points divided by total area of the polygon. Apparently that would be called the [area number density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_density). If this is not what you need, then you have to be more specific about what properties your density should satisfy.